# calling a method twice from different classes causes an out of memory error

Tags: php, oop

I have a method in a singleton class, this class its called from a parent class that is exntended by a child class.

Assume that my classes have been declared and created properly, this is just a quick run down of my coding logic.

```
class Singleton
{
    public function load_sys()
    {
        $this->something();
    }

    public function something()
    {
        $this->load();
    }

    public function load(){}
}

class Parent
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sys = Singleton::init();
        $this->sys->load_sys();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

when I do this I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4296 bytes) in ~~~.php on line 102
```

what could be causing this?

Comment: You should write the version of PHP you are using, as well as your OS. This is especially important for an OOP. These are mandatory for a valid bug report. Here is what I get when I try to run your code in CLI, PHP 5.4.0: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting '{' in /home/xxx/oop.php on line 2`.

Comment: the code above isn't workable code, its to show the order in which events are laid out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may not be due to calling a method twice but rather some errors in your code. First of all you are declaring a class with brackets:

```
class Singleton()
```

should be:

```
class Singleton
```

Also, you are declaring a class as `Parent` which is a reserved word in PHP, so try renaming that first.

Comment: Also, `Singleton` has no method named `init` and has a public constructor so it's not really a singleton. After I fix all of these errors it runs fine for me.

Comment: i gave a gist of my php logic, i assumed that people would know what I was trying to say. but there are no coding errors on my side.

Comment: I think we still need `init` though.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Godwin. Eli you are not showing the actual code, but pseudocode which can or cannot be what you have done really. As you can see errors can be made pretty easily. Try this: `var_dump($this);` on `load_sys` - are the objects same? If they are, the problem could be in load().

Comment: the problem is with load, it seems to be loading itself receptively. My code is several hundred lines long =/

Comment: If I understood right, you call every time the load_sys() [which calls something() which calls load()] when you create Parent. Well, thus your methods gets called. Is that the problem?